# Redis How to delete key by pattern

Tags: redis

it may be a duplicate but i tryed a lot and couldn't find a solution.

Here's my key which i want to del

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys Get*
1) "GetLeftMen:28.10.50.154"
2) "GetLeftMenu|28.10.50.156"
3) "GetLeftMenu|28.30.60.146"
4) "GetLeftMenu|28.30.50.146"
5) "GetLeftMenu|28.30.50.156"
6) "GetLeftMen:28.10.50.155"
7) "GetLeftMen:28.10.50.156"
```

[image]

Its a cached list data with app versions, what I tryed

```
127.0.0.1:6379> sscan --pattern Get* | xargs  -del
(error) ERR invalid cursor
127.0.0.1:6379> scan --pattern Get:*
(error) ERR invalid cursor

C:\Program Files\Redis>redis-cli --scan --pattern Get* | xargs redis-cli
'xargs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\Redis>redis-cli --raw keys "$menu" | xargs redis-cli del
'xargs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I'm using windows 10 machine, what should i do,

ChatGP says that

[image]

Any solution please?

Comment: When you're asking for help, you’ll get more/better answers if you [don’t post screenshots or photos](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Cut & paste the text directly into the message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

See also http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

ChatGPT is correct. There is no way to do delete keys from Redis with a wildcard. You need to find matching keys with [KEYS](https://redis.io/commands/keys/)—or better yet [SCAN](https://redis.io/commands/scan/)—and then [DEL](https://redis.io/commands/del/) them—or better yet [UNLINK](https://redis.io/commands/unlink/) them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command:

```
redis-cli -a yourPassIfExists keys "*Get*" | xargs -I% redis-cli -a yourPassIfExists del "%"
```